# Convert BigQueryML model to sql case when syntax

Tags: sql, machine-learning, google-bigquery

I have ML Models in the BigQuery I want to convert them to SQL select cases when syntax to make real-time predictions in local postgresDB.

I exported my model and tried xgb2sql lib but it didn't convert well. xgb2sql changed the data formats and it's not giving fields name. Is there any different way to convert models to SQL?

Something like this:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN (price <= 697000.0) THEN CASE WHEN (dom <= 15.5) THEN CASE WHEN ("country" <= 0.5) THEN CASE WHEN (matched_count <= 0.5) THEN 0.01 ELSE CASE WHEN (price <= 132500.0) THEN 0.01 ELSE CASE WHEN (price <= 259000.0) THEN CASE WHEN (matched_count <= 1.5) THEN CASE WHEN (price <= 217500.0) THEN CASE WHEN (dom <= 14.5) THEN CASE WHEN (price <= 196750.0) THEN CASE WHEN (price <= 187500.0) THEN CASE WHEN (dom <= 3.5)...
```